# C# How to Make Sure Extension Methods Signatures Match?

Tags: c#, mapping, extension-methods

```
public static class PersonPropertyMapper
{
    public static PeopleSearchBusinessLogic.DomainModels.Person ToDomainModel(this Entities.Person entity)
    {
        return new PeopleSearchBusinessLogic.DomainModels.Person()
        {
            Id = entity.Id,
            Name = entity.Name,
            Address = entity.Address,
            Age = entity.Age,
            Interests = entity.Interests,
            Picture = entity.Picture
        };
    }
}
```

As you can see here, I have a class with an extension method that converts objects back and forth. In this case the ToDomainModel method is an extension of the Entities.Person object.

It is my understanding that classes containing extension methods cannot derive from other classes or implement interfaces. However, as I add more "PropertyMappers" I would like to require all of these classes to follow the same interface so that the method names are the same across the application. I feel like there should be a simple solution to this, but this is not the first time I have come across this problem.

As an example, let's say I have a Car object and I need to create a CarPropertyMapper. Right now, there is nothing stopping me from naming the extension method as "ToCarDomainModel()" instead of the standard "ToDomainModel".

I would love a solution to solve this dilemma or at least understand why I am going about this the wrong way.

Or, is there another solution for mapping objects (e.g. Domain Models and Entities) that I have overlooked?

Comment: This is not what extension methods are for. If you want all of the methods to have the same name, make an interface for it and make all of your classes inherit from it. Extension methods are primarily used when you can't change the base class but want to add methods to it.

Comment: @Lauraducky Oh, Thank you! I think a better way to do this would just be  (as you said) to make an interface for the Entities.Person class (called IMapper) that has all of the conversion methods signatures (since the Domain Model does not know about Entities), requiring me to implement the conversion details in the Entity class. Or I could possibly use AutoMapper as mentioned below. I figured the solution wasn't as complicated as I was making it out to be.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods are static methods in static classes, of course they cannot implement interfaces or extend other classes. This is not a normal use of them, though.

Some solutions to this:

- Accept the fact that those are static classes
- Stop using extension methods and turn to an interface-oriented design
- Use a mapping library like AutoMapper